# Can you spend luck points on an opposed roll?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-7e

Can you spend luck points on an opposed roll? Specifically, an opposed POW roll, but presumably the answer would apply to other opposed rolls as well.

The rules tell us that:

1. Many types of roll can *EITHER* be pushed *OR* have luck points spent on them (if you’re using that optional rule) but never both.
2. Opposed rolls cannot be pushed.

Does point (1) above imply that *only* rolls that can be pushed can have luck points spent on them — thereby suggesting that opposed rolls cannot? The rules seem silent on this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spending luck points is one of the optional rules, so it's not that strictly defined. I've found this rule in Pulp Cthulhu manual where luck usage is way more detailed:

> A critical success only arises from a natural dice roll of “01.”
>   Should Luck points be used to lower a roll to 01 the result is
>   always an Extreme success (rather than a critical one).

And here's interesting part:

> The only
>   exception to this would be in combat where two opponents
>   have tied (both scoring Extreme successes), if one uses Luck
>   to lower their combat roll to “01” it means that they beat their
>   opponent’s level of success (treat the result as an Extreme
>   success though).

This suggests IMO that spending luck points **can be applied** to opposed rolls.

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof. I guess this is one of those “rule it however you want” issues — which is pretty much what I figured when I posted the question, given that I could find nothing definitive in the rules about it; I just wondered if I’d missed or overlooked something ‘official’. The fact that the only answer submitted in over a month references a different system (that’s in no way meant as a criticism, by the way; it’s really useful info, so thx) suggests that I didn’t miss anything, and the rules really don’t specify, so its entirely up to the GM.